# Microsoft Graph - How to test the /Security/Alerts webhook

Tags: security, graph

I have recently configured a webhook for Microsoft Graph for the following:

```
security/alerts?$filter=status eq 'newAlert'
```

How can I simulate a test alert to see if it works or is there a method that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: The only type of alerts that I managed to simulate are email related alerts by using outlook's report feature by marking an email as phishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no way to generate a test alert, unfortunately. You would have to pay for a subscription to at least of the alert providers like ASC, MCAS, AIP, MDATP, Sentinel, etc. You may be able to try a trial subscription if one is offered.

Comment: Thanks Brittany - i'll try to simulate it another way.